# Hibernate CreateQuery sum() always returning Long type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, createquery

I did a query to get the sum of values in a table:
      `List<Double> resultList = (List<Double>) em.createQuery("SELECT sum(v.prices) FROM Ship v).getResultList();`

The problem is that even though i typed as Double, the return continues to be Long and the decimals are not included.

Can someone help me with this issue? Pls

Thanks!

Comment: How is your Ship entity defined? Post the relevant code. How do you know it's a Long. Post code proving it.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
List<Double> resultList = (List<Double>) em.createQuery("SELECT sum(cast(v.prices as double)) FROM Ship v).getResultList();
```

Comment: Not really using the ORM here. If you are going to use SQL directly then why would you use an ORM at all?